# Performance Tool selection for Angular application

Tags: performance-testing

Can anyone please suggest which tool is suitable to do performance testing for Angular applications

Answer (score 1):

Performance testing tools are backend-agnostic, they don't know anything about the underlying technology so you can choose whatever you want, the main criteria is [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols support.

[Here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) you can find a list of free and open source load testing tools, the absolute majority of them supports HTTP/HTTPS protocols and even provide record-and-replay capabilities.

If you're looking for a specific recommendation you can check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article which highlights and compares several most advanced tools like:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Locust](https://locust.io/)

Still uncertain? I would recommend going for [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) as it doesn't require extra domain knowledge, you should be able to create your tests using GUI. Moreover Angular means JavaScript and in modern world JavaScript means [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and to my knowledge only JMeter as of now supports easy simulation of AJAX requests via [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md)

Comment: Since @manusa talked about Angular apps, I would suppose she is talking about end-to-end / frontend performance testing. These tools do not consider rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [my comment](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/36375/performance-tool-selection-for-angular-application#comment44450_36379) on [Dmitri's answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/36379/12740), I would add to his suggestions [Sitespeed.io](https://www.sitespeed.io/). It provides good reports with Grafana, with minimal setup, good integration with CI tools, and pre-scripts written in Javascript, which your team is already familar.

You can find examples [here](https://www.sitespeed.io/examples/).